# Case Statements in SQL - Nature of the Process

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am writing a case statement in SQL to determine if an employee is a veteran or veteran spouse.  There are three fields that contain the data and the logic would be:

1) If any of the three fields indicates veteran, the person is a veteran
2) If none indicate veteran but the last one indicates spouse, the person is a spouse

[image: Example Scenarios]

I have written a case statement that seems to work:

```
CASE
WHEN Flag1 = 'Vet' THEN 'Veteran'
WHEN Flag2 = 'Vet' THEN 'Veteran'
WHEN Flag3 = 'Vet' THEN 'Veteran'
WHEN Flag3 = 'Spouse' THEN 'Veteran Spouse'
ELSE 'Non Veteran/Spouse'
END
```

I am wondering if this works because there are no scenarios in my data that are causing to fail, not because it is written correctly.  For example, I have no data where one of the first 2 flags says vet and flag 3 is spouse (which I would expect to show as a vet).  What I want to know is: when the case statement hits it's first when that is positive, does it take action on the record and move to the next row or does it look at the next when and take action if those conditions are met as well changing the response (example: if flag1 is vet the case statement output is Veteran.  If the same row had the word spouse in flag3 would the record be changed to Veteran Spouse?)

Comment: You could add a fail case to your data and see

Comment: I think the last row of the example image is wrong relative to the text of the explanation. You should avoid posting images, and instead build that kind of example data as pre-formatted text, to make it easier to fix and easier for those of us who don't always see images to help you.

Comment: What you have is a `CASE` **expression**. `CASE` **statements** do exist, too, but not in SQL. (They exist in a programming language, PL/SQL, which you don't need to know about.) Then: The evaluation of a `CASE` expression stops as soon as the FIRST condition (in the several `WHEN` clauses) is `true`. The `CASE` expression evaluates to the corresponding `THEN` expression, and the rest of the `CASE` expression is ignored. Your code is correct, and works exactly as you expect it to work, precisely for this reason.

Comment: `case when 'Vet' in (Flag1, Flag2, Flag3) then 'Veteran' when 'Spouse' in (Flag1, Flag2, Flag3) then 'Veteran Spouse' else 'Non Veteran/Spouse'
end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is correct. The database will evaluate the `WHEN` conditions in order and use the first that matches.

For fun, you could also write it like this:

```
CASE WHEN 'Vet' IN (Flag1, Flag2, Flag3) THEN 'Veteran'
     WHEN Flag3 = 'Spouse' THEN 'Veteran Spouse'
     ELSE 'Non Veteran/Spouse'
END
```

Even better if these values are in a small lookup table you can join to.

Answer (score 0):

Joel's answer is the safer logic.  But it ironic that you can do this much more simply:

```
select greatest(flag1, flag2, flag3)
```